# Duda con el condicional if

Tags: javascript

Tengo una duda, ¿Cómo puedo hacer para que estos 3 nombres me aparezcan `correcto`  pero sin usar `else if`?:

```
let mascotas = prompt("Nombre de tu mascota ", "");
if (mascotas == "bandido"&&"simbo"&&"sofea") {
  alert("Correcto");
} else {
  alert("Incorrecto");
}
```

Comment: Hola Esteban, no estoy seguro de que necesitas, tal vez te pueda servir algo como: **alert( mascotas[ 0 ] === "bandido" && mascotas[ 1 ] === "simbo" && mascotas[ 2 ] === "sofea"  );**, el problema es que el alert te devulve "`true`" no "`Correcto`"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Antes de responder tu pregunta, me gustaría comentarte sobre un problema que noté en tu condicional.

---

En el código que tienes, sólo se cumplirá la condición `if` si el valor del `prompt` es la palabra `bandido`, ya que indicas que si el valor ingresado es igual a `bandido` (por el `==`), cumple con el `if`, pero respecto a `simbo` y `sofea` no le estás condicionando que si son iguales, ya que solo estás poniendo a esas cadenas, por lo tanto, si ingresas la palabra `simbo` o `sofea`, entrará al `else` y te devolverá `Incorrecto`.

```js
let mascotas = prompt("Nombre de tu mascota ", "");
if (mascotas == "bandido" && "simbo" && "sofea") {
  alert("Correcto");
} else {
  alert("Incorrecto");
}
```

---

Entonces, en este caso puedes utilizar el operador [**`OR`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_OR).

Aquí, En la condición `if`, indico que si el valor del `prompt`, almacenado en la variable `mascotas`, es igual a la cadena `bandido` o a `simbo` o a `sofea`, cumplimos con la condición y nos devuelve `Correcto` en consola, y si no cumple con ninguno de los 3, entra al `else`, devolviéndonos `Incorrecto`, por ejemplo:

```js
let mascotas = prompt("Nombre de tu mascota", "");
if (mascotas === "bandido" || mascotas === "simbo" || mascotas === "sofea") {
  alert("Correcto");
} else {
  alert("Incorrecto");
}
```

Y respecto a tu pregunta, para no usar `else` o `if`, podemos utilizar al operador ternario [**`?:`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_operator), en donde su sintaxis es la siguiente:

```
condición ? expr1 : expr2
```

Y en el código podemos implementarlo de la siguiente forma:

```js
let mascotas = prompt("Nombre de tu mascota", "");
(mascotas === "bandido" || mascotas === "simbo" || mascotas === "sofea") ? alert("Correcto") : alert("Incorrecto");
```

En donde:

- La condición vendría a ser todo lo que está en paréntesis, antes del `?`.
- Esta condición nos va a devolver algo, y depende a eso lo que nos devuelve, vemos qué expresión devolver.
- Si se cumple la condición (si es verdadera o `true`), devolvemos la primera expresión (que sería el `alert` con el mensaje `Correcto`).
- Si no se cumple la condición (si es falsa o `false`), devolvemos la segunda expresión (que sería el `alert` con el mensaje `Incorrecto`).

Comment: Destacar que las variables tienen un único valor a la vez. Si una variable `x = 1`, no vale ni `2` ni `3` ni `4` ni cualquier otro número. Así que la operación de interés es **O** (`||`), no **Y** (`&&`). No espero respuesta.

Comment: @Mateo Claro, pero en este caso estaban mal sus condiciones, y eso fue lo que traté de explicar, así que más fui por ese punto, de todas formas gracias por esa observación adicional.

Answer (score 2):

Para más comodidad puedes poner los nombres en una lista y mediante la función [`includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) determinar si un valor forma parte de ella:

```js
nombres = ["bandido", "simbo", "sofea"]
console.log(nombres.includes("bandido"))
```

Answer (score 1):

La idea de usar un array, como sugiere @Mateo en su respuesta, es mucho más flexible por dos motivos:

1. Si quisieras comparar por más nombres no tendrías que seguir ampliando tus `OR` *ad infinitum*, simplemente agregas el nuevo nombre al array y punto.
2. Puedes controlar errores de escritura usando el método [`toLowerCase()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase). Imagina que el usuario escribe: `Bandido`,  o `SimBo` o `SOFEA`. El nombre en sí es el mismo, pero escrito de formas distintas. Verificando el array con `includes` y aplicando `toLowerCase()` solventas ese problema sin mayores dificultades.

Veamos un ejemplo, he escrito una función para mayor utilidad, prueba a escribir combinando mayúsculas / minúsculas.

```js
const mascotas = ["bandido", "simbo", "sofea"];
let oneName = prompt("Nombre de tu mascota ", "");

checkMascota(oneName);

function checkMascota(theName) {
  console.log(mascotas.includes(theName.toLowerCase()));
}
```